# Bat скрипт закрыть файл с маской "output.docx"

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-10, bat, скрипт

Bat скрипт выполняет скрипт, и после него есть команда открыть output.docx.
Но если опять запускать этот batник, то появляеться ошибка, что файл output.docx уже запущен (и он открыт).

1) Что надо написать в bat-файле, чтобы всегда когда он начинает выполняться дальше, если есть открытое окно с точным названием output.docx, закрыть принудительно?
taskkill?

2) та же сама задача но если файл имеет маску *.docx

Comment: что происходит с файлом output.docx? Просмотр, печать?

Comment: просмотр, просто открываеться

Comment: вопрос в том что нужно написать, если при следующих запусках батника, он не может быть выполнен, если открыт вордовский файл. Какую комманду(ы) в начале скприпта поставить на условие: "Если открыт (существует) файл с называнием "output.docx, то закрыть""

Comment: А может проще без проверки сразу отправлять команду на завершение процессу, чей PID соответствует окну с текстом в начале заголовка: **output.docx**. Например, так: **taskkill /fi "windowtitle eq output.docx*"**